# Difference between Fluent NHibernate and Nhibernate.Mapping.ByCode

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

What is the difference? Should I consider Fluent NH outdated since NH 3.2?

Comment: I'm still using FNH with NH 3.2.  The NuGet package is compatible with this version.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are few major differences - FNH is well established and quite popular, but mapping-by-code is more powerful, better coupled with NHibernate features and I find it much more elegant.

I'd like to suggest you to read my blog series comparing mapping-by-code to Fluent NHibernate - **[here](http://notherdev.blogspot.com/2012/02/nhibernates-mapping-by-code-summary.html)** is the table of contents and my final conclusions.

Comment: I love your series. Excellent reference.

Comment: This seems very good.  I'm glad to see someone has taken the time to explain mapping by code.  This is one reason why I've never considered switching from FNH to MBC.

Comment: FNH has some features which are missing in MbC hence i wouldn't say "is more powerful" but rather it "more powerful in some scenarios".

Answer (score 2):

FNH

- more mature and popular
- Fluent API leads you more - better for beginners
- a lot of good documentation

Mapping by code
- uses the loquacious API-style which is far easier to implement hence far fewer quirks/inconsistencies
- comes with NHibernate so more up to date featurewise

both lack different features and have different bugs. FNH has almost stalled since the release of Mappnig by code